# Tensor Flow Mninst external image prediction not working

Tags: python, image-processing, classification, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

i am new to neural networks. i have gone through TensorFlow mninst ML Beginners

used tensorflow basic mnist tutorial

and trying to get prediction using external image enter image description here

I have the updated the mnist example provided by tensorflow

```
On top of that i have added few things :
1. Saving trained models locally
2. loading the saved models.
3. preprocessing the image into 28 * 28.

i have attached the image for reference

 1. while training the models, save it locally. So i can reuse it at any point of time.
 2. once after training, loading the models.
 3. creating an external image via gimp which contains any one values ranging from [0 - 9]
 4. using opencv to convert the image into 28 * 28 image and reversing the bit as well.
 5. Then trying to predict.
```

i am able to train the models and save it properly.

i am getting predictions which are not right.

Find my codes Below

1.TrainSimple.py

```
    # Load MNIST Data
    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

    from random import randint
    from scipy import misc

    # Start TensorFlow InteractiveSession
    import tensorflow as tf
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

    # Placeholders
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

    # Variables
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    # Predicted Class and Cost Function
    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)
    cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y))

    saver = tf.train.Saver()  # defaults to saving all variables

    # GradientDescentOptimizer
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)


    # Train the Model

       for i in range(40000):
            if (i + 1) == 40000 :
                saver.save(sess, "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/TensorFlow/"+"/model.ckpt", global_step=i)
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
        train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})

    # Evaluate the Model
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))

    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    print(accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

2. loadImageAndPredict.py

   ```
   from random import randint
   from scipy import misc
   import numpy as np
   import cv2

   def preProcess(invert_file):
       print "preprocessing the images" + invert_file
       image=cv2.imread(invert_file,0)
       ret,image_thresh = cv2.threshold(image,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
       l,b=image.shape

       fr=0
       lr=0
       fc=0
       lc=0

       i=0
       while len(set(image_thresh[i,]))==1:
           i+=1
       fr=i

       i=0
       while len(set(image_thresh[-1+i,]))==1:
           i-=1
       lr=i+l

       j=0
       while len(set(image_thresh[0:,j]))==1:
           j+=1
       fc=j

       j=0
       while len(set(image_thresh[0:,-1+j]))==1:
           j-=1
       lc=j+b

       image_crop=image_thresh[fr:lr,fc:lc]
       image_padded= cv2.copyMakeBorder(image_crop,5,5,5,5,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=255)
       image_resized = cv2.resize(image_padded, (28, 28))
       image_resized = (255-image_resized)
       cv2.imwrite(invert_file, image_resized)

   import tensorflow as tf
   sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

   # Placeholders
   x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
   y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

   # # Variables
   W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
   b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))



   # Predicted Class and Cost Function
   y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)
   cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))

   saver = tf.train.Saver()  # defaults to saving all variables - in this case w and b

   # Train the Model
   # GradientDescentOptimizer
   train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
   flag_1 = 0

   # create an an array where we can store 1 picture
   images = np.zeros((1,784))
   # and the correct values
   correct_vals = np.zeros((1,10))


   preProcess("4_white.png")

   gray = cv2.imread("4_white.png", 0)

   flatten = gray.flatten() / 255.0
   """
   we need to store the flatten image and generate
   the correct_vals array
   correct_val for a digit (9) would be
   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
   """
   images[0] = flatten
   # print images[0]
   print len(images[0])

   sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

   ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state("/Users/xxxx/Desktop/TensorFlow")
   if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
       saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
       my_classification = sess.run(tf.argmax(y, 1), feed_dict={x: [images[0]]})
       print 'Neural Network predicted', my_classification[0], "for your digit"
   ```

i am not sure what mistake i have done.

Thinking that simple model might not work i have used this convolution code to predict.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py

Even that does not predict properly :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensor Flow Mninst example prediction using external image does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865622/tensor-flow-mninst-example-prediction-using-external-image-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

1. Does your training loss go down?
2. Do you get high accuracy on training dataset?
3. Do you get high accuracy on validation dataset (part of training set set aside?)
4. Do you get high accuracy on your target dataset?

If you have low training loss (1.), then you are not learning, and need to try different hyper-parameters, such as learning rates.

If you have high (2.) and low (3.), you are overfitting, and need to train for less long, or have higher regularization penalty. If you have high (3.) and low (4.), your training set is not representative of your actual set. Need to make your training set more representative, or at least harder, for instance, by adding distortions

Comment: i started with this https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/index.html

On Top the above tutorial, i wrote code to get external image and pass it on to the predictor in required format (28 * 28) in numpy.array.
So it can predict the number properly.